# Can I Override Global Authentication for a Single Request Type in an ApiView using DRF?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm using django_rest_frameork (DRF) on a large project.  In general, I want all my views protected, so I have Token Authentication set as my global authentication scheme.  But there are a few views that I want this turned off, for example, creating a new user, and logging in.

For example my `/User` ApiView has a `get` and `post` method.  The `get` returns the user profile and the `post` creates a new user. How can I override the global authetication scheme on the `/User` `post` only?  I still need it turned on when getting user information.

I'm asking more to increase my understanding of DRF than anything.  I know that I could separate the `/User/` calls into to different ApiViews, where one is authenticated and one isn't.  I also know that I could dispense with the global scheme entirely and authenticate on a pre-view basis.

Is there a particularly "pythonic" or django-typical way of doing this?  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

You can write custom [permission class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) and use it in some views. For example:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class AllowPostAny(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == "POST":
            return True
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

You can now use this permission in view:

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowPostAny]
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks perfect.  If I have the global authentication scheme enabled, and then I add this to some particular view, will the specific view's authentication class override the global authentication, or will the request have to be authenticated by both auth classes?

Comment: @Brian permission is actually is not authentication. It's a little different thing and doesn't change authentication process. You can think about it as an additional layer which helps you customize access to specific views or objects. Note that there in default permission class is DRF. And when you define `permission_classes` on view level you override it. But again it doesn't override authentication class. Please check authentication patr of documentation:https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ Hope it make difference between auth and permission classes more clear.